# MS-SQL Query to show max value in list of duplicates

Tags: sql-server

The scenario is that I have an access table that contains rows of data for users access, and it also contains an Access Level which has either a 1 or a 2. The 1 denotes 'User' and 2 for 'Admin'. The problem is though that a user can contain both of those values (Access source coming from a variety of other systems that feed into this table).

Therefore, my problem is, how do I write a query that will return a list of users and their access level, where it ONLY shows the max value that the user has for a given Department?

```
Username        | Department  | AccessLevel
---------------------------------------------
John Smith      | IT          | 1
John Smith      | IT          | 2
John Smith      | Security    | 2
Sally Harris    | Security    | 1
Craig Larry     | IT          | 1
```

As you can see the table contains two records from John Smith, with the second having a higher access level.

The results I would like would be

```
John Smith   | IT       | 2
John Smith   | Security | 2
Sally Harris | Security | 1
Craig Larry  | IT       | 1
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Select DISTINCT(Username), Department, MAX(AccessLevel )
From departmentaccess
Group By Username, Department, AccessLevel
```

The results I get back are exactly as what is in the table. I believe this query I am trying returns the Max record for rows that are entirely duplicate.

What can I do to improve this to get only my expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you should be aggregating only by username and department:

```
SELECT Username, Department, MAX(AccessLevel)
FROM departmentaccess
GROUP BY Username, Department;
```

A more general query which would work if there were more columns in the table which did not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Username, Department, AccessLevel, other_column
FROM departmentaccess
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username, Department ORDER BY AccessLevel DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove group by `AccessLevel`

```
Select Username, Department, MAX(AccessLevel )
From departmentaccess
Group By Username, Department
```